# Xpath to grab corresponding child element

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to output a specific child element corresponding to the position of a completely separate child element. ie:

```
<FIRSTLIST>
    <ITEM>item a<ITEM>
    <ITEM>item b<ITEM>
    <ITEM>item c<ITEM>
</FIRSTLIST>

<SECONDLIST>
    <ITEM>no<ITEM>
    <ITEM>no<ITEM>
    <ITEM>yes<ITEM>
</SECONDLIST>
```

"yes could be anywhere within SECONDLIST so as "yes" is 3rd in the list in this example, I want to output the 3rd item from FIRSTLIST. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Could you do some more clarification? do you required `item c` from firstlist or `yes` from secondlist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
//FIRSTLIST/ITEM[position()=count(//SECONDLIST/ITEM[text()="yes"]/preceding-sibling::ITEM)+1]
```

to match required `ITEM`

If your tool supports `XPath 2.0` you also might use

```
//FIRSTLIST/ITEM[position()=index-of(//SECONDLIST/ITEM, //SECONDLIST/ITEM[text()="yes"])]
```

Comment: Thanks, but its the item in the FIRSTLIST i want to output thats in the same position as the "yes" in the SECONDLIST

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help

Comment: If there were 2 instances of "yes" would it be possible to only output the latter one?

Comment: This already should return the last one... Does it returns first one?